# Removing duplicate rows in MySQL by merging info

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with person info. Every record has an ID and is referenced by other tables. I noticed that a lot of records have duplicate keys, but they vary in the amount of information in the other fields. I'd like to merge the info in various fields into one and make that the 'master' record and all references to the other records need to be replaced with the master record.

An example

```
| id | key1 | key2 | name | city | dob      |
|--- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | -------- |
| 1  | 1    | 2    | John |      |          |
| 2  | 1    | 2    |      | Town |          |
| 3  | 1    | 2    | John |      | 70/09/12 |
```

I need to end up with a single record (id is either 1, 2 or 3) with values
key1 = 1, key2 = 2, name = John, city = Town, dob = 70/09/12.

Is there a clever way to merge these records without testing for every field (my actual table has a lot of fields)?

Comment: Remember to use `DATE` columns for any date-type data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` to get the non-empty values for each key.

```
SELECT key1, key2, MAX(id) AS id, MAX(name) AS name, MAX(city) AS city, MAX(dob) AS dob
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY key1, key2
```

If there can be different values between rows, and you don't want to include them, you can add:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(name, ''), NULLIF(city, ''), NULLIF(dob, '')) = 1
```

Comment: This comes close. Thanks a lot ! I now see that sometimes the fields are still different (e.g. name = John in one and Joe in another record). So I just need to exclude some keys.

Comment: testing it right now. Is there a difference (in meaning or performance) between if(name = '', NULL, name) and nullif(name,'') ?

Comment: No, I just forgot about `NULLIF`.

Comment: hmm, applying this to my actual table and now it returns nothing. So the first part (without the having count....) returns 671 records. With the having clause I get nothing. Does this mean exclude any record that has any of these fields empty?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data to play with?

Comment: I'm trying to get some data together, but need to consider privacy issues. In the mean time I find that the difference is mostly in records that have empty key1 and/or key2 fields.

Comment: I assumed that these key fields would always be filled in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155544/discussion-between-hepabolu-and-barmar).